# Django admin radio-button for one-to-one relationship

Tags: python, django, one-to-one, modeladmin

I have 2 model classes in my django app:
1: House (name, location, id...)
2: Photo (description, id, house -foreign key-).

In the admin interface, the photo is displayed as inline for the house form, but now, I want the user to be able to choose ONE picture as highlighted for that house. 
My question is: there's someway to add a radiobutton so the user is only able to choose one picture?
Could you help me to achieve this, please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `OneToOneField` for `Photo` in `House` model (you will need to reference it as `"YOUR_APP.Photo"` to avoid circular references), provide `ModelAdmin` with custom form, and in that form's constructor filter queryset for that field to display only photos for current house.

Different approach is to add `highlighted` flag in `Photo` model and ensure on `save` that only one photo is highlighted for one house.